# How to complete function for points to be on the line, not on axis y = 0 using Matplotlib?

Tags: python, function, matplotlib, plot, data-visualization

I have a piece of code and need to complete ema_func2 so the dots would be on the orange line

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt    
import numpy as np

halflife = 0.25
resolution_per_second = 1000
values = np.concatenate([np.zeros(resolution_per_second),
                         np.ones(resolution_per_second * 2),
                         np.zeros(resolution_per_second),
                         np.ones(resolution_per_second * 1),
                         np.zeros(resolution_per_second * 2),
                         ])
t_grid = np.arange(0, len(values)) / resolution_per_second
step = 1.0 / resolution_per_second
k = np.power(0.5, 1 / (halflife * resolution_per_second))

def ema_fixed_step(y, k): #ema method 1 on chart
    res = np.zeros_like(y)
    curV = y[0]
    for i in range(1, len(y) - 1):
        curV = k * curV + (1 - k) * y[i]
        res[i + 1] = curV
    return res

ema1_arr = ema_fixed_step(values, k)

#
w = values != np.roll(values, 1)
w[0] = True
t_new = t_grid[w]
values_new = values[w]
t_extra = [0.6, 1.0001, 1.2, 1.5, 2.9, 4.5, 3.3, 5.5]

t_req = np.sort(np.concatenate([t_new, t_extra]))


def ema_func2(t_req, t, y): #ema method 2 on chart
    return np.zeros_like(t_req, dtype=np.double)

ema2_arr = ema_func2(t_req, t_new, values_new)

plt.clf()
plt.step(t_grid, values, '.-', where='post', label='y')
plt.step(t_grid, ema1_arr, '.-', where='post', label='ema method 1')
plt.plot(t_req, ema2_arr, 'o', color='red', markersize=4, label='ema method 2')


plt.grid()
plt.legend()
plt.xlabel('t, seconds')
```

That's the part of code and that's the result:

[image]

And, as I said above, need to complete function for those red dots appear on the orange curve. So, I need to take some piece from ema_fixed_step and somehow alter it according to t_req. How could it be done?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What should I add to add red-markers on the orange curve in Matplotlib?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55172607/what-should-i-add-to-add-red-markers-on-the-orange-curve-in-matplotlib)

Comment: @Reedinationer yup, I asked again here due to the necessity of making it another way. As it turned out, I need to change function, not to make it the way you did it. Sorry )

Comment: I think you will need to explain more the specific product you need at the end then and how it is different from the previous post

Comment: How can the red points fall on the orange curve if red points are all zero? `ema2_arr` is nothing else but an array of zeros

Comment: @Reedinationer well, your decision was great, but in my case, not valid. I need to make somehow function, that uses analytical methods, so as if it would be 2 different functions for orange curve and red dots

Comment: @Bazingaa that's the whole point, I need to edit it, so it would be not zero

Comment: @Bazingaa take a look at my answer on the post that I linked as possible duplicate for an example

Comment: I do have some problems understanding in how far the linked answer does not help here. Can you maybe spend more than two sentences on the differences and what exact outcome you need?